# Print out PNG image on transparent sheet

Tags: print-design, transparency, png

I have created two PNG images with 0.4 opacity, which I want to print out on transparent plastic paper, purpose is to see lower sheet text and images show little bit clear from the above printed sheet.

So my question is that if it is possible to print out PNG transparent(0.4 opacity) image on transparent plastic sheet, which looks as transparent to see both the upper and lower image design on it ? And if yes, what printer required to complete this on plastic sheet ?

Something like this

[image]
*Photo source google*

I wasn't able to find out any particular answer on this, so please let me know if this is duplicate of any question or this is not a suitable question for this site.

Comment: Do you intend to have this printed at a professional shop or with a regular home/office printer?

Comment: Professional Shop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a specific answer there is some missing data in the question:

1. the software used
2. full color design or just one or two inks
3. home or professional printing

——————————————————————

Talking about the background, it doesn't need to be transparent to print over a transparent support. The white background in print means no ink (non printed area).

Talking about the design (printed area):

- In printing the transparency is not the opacity, but percentage of ink density:

[image: ink density]

Higher density percentage = more opaque = the support is fully or largely covered with ink

Lower density percentage = more transparent = the support is partially covered with ink dots

[image]

The transparency is for effects on a file with other elements, but the result is a mix of inks.

Reducing the ink density decrease the diameter of printing dots, what in a transparent support allows to see through.

[image: transp]

- About the print file format, I don't think PNG will be the best. Here you have a full description:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/58929/120647

- Printing system, for a few labels today digital print do all types of supports and inks. If it's for a professional printing or large quantities, the most widely used printing systems for transparent support are flexography (cheaper and a little lower quality) and silkscreen printing.

Comment: I have created this with photoshop and i have used opacity, I may need to check ink density to create my image.

Comment: @KirankumarDafda How many colors (inks)? I would recommend a vector program like Indesign, Illustrator, QuarkXpress, Word.

Comment: It's a photo captured in a garden so you can understand colors of it.

Comment: Well thanks for the info, i will google it and update you for the same.

Comment: ok, is a bit mor complicated. This is another question: **how to get a semitransparent photographic image printed on a transparent support**. The image on your question is a one ink logo.

Comment: Yes, it is. But will print one demo picture and then check the density of it.

Comment: Nitpicking but – doesn't a white background depend on the printer/program used? E.g. if a white background layer was used in Photoshop, then sent to print on an RGB printer, it would actually print that white background layer on something like transparent film.

Comment: @alxmntrvl White ink doesn't exist in a CMYK process printing. 
White = 0% C + 0% M + 0% Y + 0% K = Non printed area. RGB printing? I never heard about it, RGB is light and light doesn't print.

Comment: Some digital printers print with white ink, but must be included on the design as special spot ink (not CMYK, and of course not RGB)

Comment: Some of the print vendors we work with use RGB-based printers (which isn't to say RGB-based inks) that  print white ink based on the RGB model. How it works I'm not sure. Not trying to get off topic, just not sure "The white background in print means no ink (non printed area)" is 100% true in every case.

Comment: Ok, on **traditional printing process** is 100% true.